# What Should I Do With My Soil?

Tags: soil, tomatoes, transplanting, eggplant

Location: Palm Beach, FL - zone 10A

My garden was infested with weevils and some other kind of fungi. I sprayed it with Monterey Garden Insect spray a week ago. This week, I noticed that my plants are dying. I have some new plants that I am ready to put in the ground. Is there a way to decontaminate the soil that I have now and reuse it? Purchasing new soil is not in my expense at the moment. I am adding some pictures of the plants,so you can have an idea of how they look..

[image: This is one of my eggplant]
[image: This tomato plant was looking really healthy two weeks ago. Now, you can see the brown and yellow spots.]
[image: Another angle of the tomato plant]
[image: This are new plants that I want to transplant.]

Comment: More information would be helpful. What area of the world are you gardening in? How much longer is your growing season. What seedlings do you have to plant (it looks like tomato and sage, but I'm not sure what the others are)? Is there another spot in your yard where you could plant the tomato seedlings (because I wouldn't put them in the same bed you've got the tomatoes in now)?

Comment: I don't have another spot to plants them. I'll have to purchase another raise bed which is not in my budget at the moment. In Florida, we may be able to grow during the fall since it does not usually get too cold here.

Comment: Is there a reason you would need to use a raised bed with purchased soil to plant them?

Comment: No, there is no specific reasons for doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found in my gardens in the past when I had done pretty much the same thing a friend told me to use a mixture of carbon (or wood ash) with coffee grounds that it would help detoxify the soil and it worked for me I just worked in the mixture with a fork about 2 inches of the top soil and watered it as normal.

Comment: I've not been able to find woodash at all in the Florida area.

Comment: I should of explained a bit more, what I meant by wood ash is if you burn wood like in a fireplace or burn barrel, the ash after you burn it and is cooled down, mix it with dried coffee grounds and work the mixture into the top 2-3 inches of the top soil the amount depends on how large the area but I always did equal parts soil, ash, and coffee grounds.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't use wood at all given I live in FL and don't do too many things that's involved burning wood, lol.

Comment: in most soils I have come across in the past 20 years the one thing they all seemed to need is carbon for some reason and in one case the soil need calcium and for that I used ground up egg shells and it worked great for me. how about burning some pieces of cardboard or paper in a metal pail or something or even a grill?

Comment: I am curious, why turn to chemicals for pest control? I am in Pa. and although harder to find these days there is a garden place here I buy ladybugs and praying mantis n such when I need pests control I think I bout about 100 praying mantis for like 5 dollars and just placed them on my plants and in no time they took care of my pest problems they are very beneficial to your garden to have some. I even had to make my own traps when I had some Japanese beetles land on my gardens.

Comment: I have only use the monterey spray so far, and it is the closest to organic that one can find. I do have an appointment with this lady to get sone lady bug eggs. Also, I've read about the shell eggs, and I an collecting then now. Lastly, I do have a charcoal grill which I can use the ash forbmy garden.

Comment: sounds good, :) well it sounds like you got everything in the works then. :) let me know how things go or if you have any more questions just ask. and good luck to you. :)

Comment: Ummm, Debra...it is great to try new concoctions for your garden.  Please be careful to quote chemicals if there isn't scientific literature to support the chemistry and logic.  Ash and coffee grounds have not been indicated by research to be beneficial.  Lady bugs are great BUT if you release them on YOUR property they are programmed to LEAVE your area and end up on your neighbor's property.  OK to experiment but unless you are using scientific methods you just can't be sure of the results enough to promote.

Comment: Gotta add a bit more here...without a real soil test ADDING anything to your soil is in my opinion crazy.  Know WHY and how much and how often you are adding anything.  This is a chance to learn how environments work, their cycles, soil is an incredible science all by itself...not to mention learning the differences between plants and animals.  Before ADDING ANYTHING please get a soil test that will tell you what chemicals are in excess and what are deficient.

Comment: True a soil test is always best. wish I knew where to show you the information online here. I was a member of the FFA (future farmers of America) for over 20 years and the 4H club I have worked with so many types of soils and I have never heard of the mixture I am referring to ever hurt any soil or food gardens or otherwise. That is I have never heard of any till now. I do believe though that being prudent is always wise. :) thanks for the information. :)